# Young girl punishment marry

Tags: nikah, punishment, age

I want to know if according to Islamic rule if young m girl kid has to accept marry the old husband and if she refuses she will get punishment, is it true or not

Answer (score -1):

I am not a Sheikh, but forcing anyone to marry is not right. In Islam after a girl has attained puberty has the right to refuse a husband. The role of the parents is to guide the child to Islamic understanding.